# Get calculated width of dynamically added UI element

Tags: android

In my android app, I try to publish some data on `ButtonClick`.

I've created separate layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <TableLayout
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="3" >

            <TableRow>
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/TV1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:text="@string/strTV1" />
            </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>

    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/overallPortraitIV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" 
            android:contentDescription="@string/strPortrait"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

My onClick event:

```
View view = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.overall_rfid_layout, null);
        overallResultTab.addView(view);
ImageView portraitImage=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.overallRfidPortraitIV);
        decodedByte = scaleToFitWidth(decodedByte, portraitImage.getMeasuredWidth());
        portraitImage.setImageBitmap(decodedByte);
```

As you see, my ImageView width is set to 0, but it has weight, so, factical width should not be 0. So how to get amount of pixels, which factically are occupied by the `ImageView`?

As shown in code, I've tried to `getMeasuredWidth`, also, `getWidth`, but they return 0;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are measuring **ImageView**'s width before setting any image to the view thats why **getMeasuredWidth** returning 0. In your **XML**, you set the layout_width to "0dip" so before setting any image to this ImageView it's width will remain "0dip".

Comment: And in this case Weight doesn not have any effect?

Comment: no...it does not have any effect. It will be effected by the Weight only when The ImageView have an Image.

Comment: But how to resolve situation, when I want to fit image into ImageView without any effect to layout? In my case, ImageView takes 1/4 width of the screen - how to make image equally wide?

Comment: You can give a try with **android:layout_width="fill_parent"**. But I will request you to post your full Layout file...then I can help you properly.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion with fill_parent, but getWidth() as well as getMeasuredWidth() returns 0; Also, I've updated my layout code here.

Comment: If you want fit your image into ImageView then you should use **android:scaleType="fitXY"** in your xml...like...
**<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/overallPortraitIV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:contentDescription="@string/strPortrait"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"/>**

Comment: I've got my desired result, by setting android:layout_height="wrap_content" and android:scaleType="center_crop" - images filled ImageView by X and stretched it to required height. Thank you!